# How do I avoid duplicate entries?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I added a liking system with a like class, whenever a user likes a post it will be added to an array based on their user. Whenever the button is clicked, a new entry is created even if the user pointer already exists, how do I avoid this?

[image]

```
func loved(sender: UIButton){
   let query = PFQuery(className: "Like")
     var object = PFObject(className: "Like")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (likes: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if(likes?.count > 0){
            object.addUniqueObject(self.playertitle.text!, forKey: "LikedSongsTitle")
            object.addUniqueObject(self.playerartist.text!, forKey: "LikedSongsArtist")
        }
        object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if(error != nil){
                print(error)
            }else{

                print("saved")
            }
        })
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new `"Like"` object and saving it as your code shows, you'll first need to query this table to determine if there's already a row for that user. If it returns a result, you can then call `addUniqueObject` on that existing object and save it. Otherwise, you can create a new object just as you've already done.

Your query might look something like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Like")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (likes: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    //if likes.count > 0 you already have a like - just update it and save
    //otherwise create a new Like object and save it
}
```

You may wish to revisit how this works though. Arrays for song titles and artists does not seem to be a good way to accomplish what you're after here - especially if you add more info such as album or year etc. A pointer to a Song class would be much more appropriate.

Comment: I updated my code, and it still does the same thing, I know the error, I just don't know how to fix it. How do I add an object to the array for that specific user. That's what I am missing.

Comment: @stackerleet You're still creating a new object and saving it no matter the result of the query. You should not create a new object in the case `likes.count > 0` but instead grab the first `like` in `likes`, update it, then save that `like`. Only create a new object if `likes.count == 0`.

Comment: So how would it look if I want to add a string the the array? cause like does not have a addUniqueObject method.

Comment: likes is an optional array of AnyObject, you need to change that to PFObject as my code shows